# How to query a single Uri, then get a Cursor object that point at the Uri item?

Tags: android, cursor

The Uri like this:

```
com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r431-E08CD8E00524/436
```

This is my way:

```
Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(entityUri, ContactQuery.COLUMNS, null, null, null);
```

It always crashed! Please help me, thanks!

```
The crash log is below:
 V/ContactTileView(  275):     
 mLookupUricontent://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r80-29121422/77
 V/ContactTileView(  275):       
 entityUricontent://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r80-29121422/77/entities
 D/AndroidRuntime(  275): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm(  275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception               
 (group=0x409f61f8)
 I/am_crash(   88):   
[275,com.android.contacts,572997,android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException,Index -1 requested, with a size of 2,AbstractCursor.java,434]
```

I use the lookup key directly:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(lookupUri, ContactQuery.COLUMNS, null, null, null);
```

And the crash log is little different:

```
/ContactTileView(  276):     
mLookupUricontent://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r285-E00EFAE00580/286
D/AndroidRuntime(  276): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0x409de1f8)
I/content_query_sample(  276): [content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r285-E00EFAE00580/286,_id/display_name/display_name_alt/sort_key/starred/contact_presence/contact_status/photo_id/photo_thumb_uri/lookup/phonetic_name/has_phone_number/is_user_profile,,,41,com.android.contacts,9]
I/am_crash(   88):    
[276,com.android.contacts,572997,android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException,Index -1 requested, with a size of 1,AbstractCursor.java,434]
D/dalvikvm(  276): GC_CONCURRENT freed 111K, 3% free 7697K/7879K, paused 2ms+3ms
E/StrictMode(  276): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
E/StrictMode(  276): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
E/StrictMode(  276):    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.<init>(ContentResolver.java:1581)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:320)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at com.android.contacts.list.ContactTileView.queryForCursor(ContactTileView.java:249)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at com.android.contacts.list.ContactTileListContextMenuAdapter.onLongClick(ContactTileListContextMenuAdapter.java:83)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at com.android.contacts.list.ContactTileView$2.onLongClick(ContactTileView.java:121)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:3498)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:13961)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/StrictMode(  276):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Above all, I think my requirement is that I can get a cursor via a lookup uri. Then I can get all the information from this Contact via this cursor. Thanks very much.

Comment: what is your requirement tell that?

Comment: Please post a stacktrace of the crash

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my question! It's easy! It's ok for my code, but I must call curosr.moveToFist after calling query.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,, and solved it by calling the close method when I need not use cursor any more.